# Find the word behind the index numbers in python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a question as I am new at the NLP. I have a dataframe consists of 2 columns. The first has a sentence lets say "Hello World, how are you?" and the second column has [6,7,8,9,10] which represents the word "World" (index positions) from the first sentence. Is there any function in python which can give me the opportunity to recognize and appear the word that in each row is specified by the index numbers?

Thank you

https://ibb.co/LRnWM7G

Comment: `df['sentence'][6:10]` will do it. Please post a snippet of your data. Sounds like the second column is a Python list of integers (indices). It would probably have been better if you had just split the sentence, rather than passing a list of indices.

Comment: i added a screenshot of the data! I cannot use the [6:10] as every time the words are in different positions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's what you need (updated according to comments)

```
dataframe = ["Hello World",[6,7,8,9,10]],
                    ["Hello World",[6,7,8,9]],
                    ["Hello World",[7,8,9,10]]
resultdataframe=[]

def textbyindexlist(df):
    text = df[0]
    letterindex=df[1]
    newtext=""
    for ind in letterindex:
        newtext = newtext + text[ind]
    return newtext
for i in dataframe:
    resultdataframe.append(textbyindexlist(i))
print (resultdataframe)
```

Comment: This seems to work but just a question. How can i make it work for my dataframe because whenever i try to pass the dataframe name inside the created function i take a message of "string indices must be integers".

Comment: My code works when the function get row by row, you should iterate through dataframe to get dataframe with all result text. I made corrections to my answer